# Under what condition, $g_T(t)\cos(2\pi f_c t)$ and $g_T(t)\sin(2\pi f_c t)$ are orthogonal?

Tags: integration, inner-products

$g_T(t)$ is a function which is equal to zero outside the interval $[0, T]$. $f_c=n/T$, where $n$ is a positive integer. Under what condition, $g_T(t)\cos(2\pi f_c t)$ and $g_T(t)\sin(2\pi f_c t)$ are orthogonal?

Note: We say that $g_T(t)\cos(2\pi f_c t)$ and $g_T(t)\sin(2\pi f_c t)$ are orthogonal if
$$ \int_0^T g_T^2(t) \cos(2\pi f_c t) \sin(2\pi f_c t) dt = 0. $$

Comment: I fail to see a question here.

Comment: do u wants us to prove integral is zero.

Comment: My question is: Under what condition, $g_T(t)\cos(2πf_ct)$ and $g_T(t)\sin(2πf_ct)$ are orthogonal? In other words, under what condition, the integral is zero?

Comment: Then this is NARQ.

Comment: What does NARQ stand for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^Tg_T^2(t)\cos(2\pi f_ct)\sin(2\pi f_ct)\,\mathrm{d}t
&=\frac12\int_0^Tg_T^2(t)\sin(4\pi nt/T)\,\mathrm{d}t
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, if the $2n^{\text{th}}$ $\sin$ coefficient of the Fourier Series for $g_T^2$ is $0$, the integral vanishes.